# #if DEBUG condition at AppDelegate.m file never caught

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, onesignal

I have upgrade my project from react-native 0.57.8 to 0.59.3. Follewed theses changes https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/compare/version/0.57.8...version/0.59.3
The problem is - when I try to run project on IOS simulator I have

> No bundle URL present

But when I remove this  condition from `AppDelegate.m` file

And left just return

> [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

Problem dissapears. So the question is why `DEBUG` condition does not work

UPD: it is not relative to Updating (because I checked at previous build and DEBUG condition does not work)
UPD2: I checked my commits and understood that after installing 'react-native-onesignal' it became to always run release version even if it is set to debug at my app schema

Answer (score 3):

Can you check in XCode's `Build Settings` if DEBUG key exists under `Preprocessor Macros`? If not expand it and for Debug field add `DEBUG=1`.
See this image [Preprocessor Macros example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fuxo.png)

Comment: Yes, DEBUG key exists

Comment: At first it looked like it existed but when double clicking the debug section, it didn't show up in the list. Adding it fixed my problem.